# why is chmod not working

Tags: command-line, permissions

I have a file, I want it to be marked read, write, execute for all.

I have tried the chmod command, but it doesnt do anything?

```
e@sx:/media/e/XXX$ ls -al
-rw-r--r--  1 e    e    34336 Apr 15 18:08 2048.uze
e@sx:/media/e/XXX$ chmod a+rwx  2048.uze 
e@sx:/media/e/XXX$ ls -al
-rw-r--r--  1 e    e    34336 Apr 15 18:08 2048.uze
e@sx:/media/e/XXX$ chmod a+rwx  2048.uze 
e@sx:/media/e/XXX$ sudo chmod a+rwx  2048.uze 
[sudo] password for e: 
e@sx:/media/e/XXX$ ls -al
-rw-r--r--  1 e    e    34336 Apr 15 18:08 2048.uze
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `/media/e` a FAT or NTFS drive? if so, see [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

Comment: I see that  this is in the directory *media*. Is this, by any chance a CD or DVD?

Comment: If the user would otherwise be permitted to change the mode of a file, the direct cause of `chmod` failure is either a read-only filesystem, or a filesystem which cannot represent UNIX file modes.